# Strange errors when making queries to excel

Tags: vb.net, excel

Im making an application in vb.net to connect to an Excel file and edit it.

At the moment attempting to modify the Excel file ,the following errors appear:

With this function

```
Protected Friend Function obtenerHojaActual(ByVal columna As String, ByVal con As String) As String
    Dim cmd As String
    Dim WorkSheet As String = ""
    Try
        libro = app.Workbooks.Open(con)
        For Each hoja As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet In libro.Worksheets
            cmd = "SELECT [" & columna & "] FROM [" & hoja.Name & "$]"
            Dim adapter As New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd, conexion)
            Dim tabla As New DataTable
            adapter.Fill(tabla)
            adapter.Dispose()
            //Code
            //Code
            //Code
            tabla.Dispose()
        Next
        libro.Close()
        app.Quit()
        Return WorkSheet
    Catch ex As Exception
        repairmanMessage("Error inesperado", ex.Message, My.Resources._error).ShowDialog()
        principal.lbldireccion.ForeColor = Color.Red
        Return WorkSheet
    End Try
End Function
```

Got this:

[image]

*"No specified values ​​for some of the parameters required"*

And with this:

```
Protected Friend Function obtenerErrores(ByVal columna As String, ByVal hoja As String, ByVal tipo As String) As Integer
    Dim cmd As String = "SELECT [" & columna & "] FROM [" & hoja & "$]"
    Dim errores As Integer = 0
    Dim fecha As Date
    Dim tabla As New DataTable
    Try
        Dim adapter As New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd, conexion)
        adapter.Fill(tabla)
        adapter.Dispose()
        //Code
        //Code
        //Code
        tabla.Dispose()
        Return errores
    Catch ex As Exception
        repairmanMessage("Error inesperado", ex.Message, My.Resources._error).ShowDialog()
        principal.lbldireccion.ForeColor = Color.Red
        Return errores
    End Try
```

Get this error...

[image]

I tried using parameterized queries, but looks like excel dont works fine with that thing (or maybe, i dont know the syntax of the query of that to use with excel).

The strangest thing of all is that in other parts of the code , do not give me errors , the program just throws errors when Im trying to modify the file, and 
although I get these two errors , excel sheet is modified just as I wanted ..

What can be ?

Comment: Do you have an `InnerException` in your `Exception` object? Those usually tell you what parameter is missing.

Comment: No... let me add it and see

Comment: I inserted what you tell me , and prints me a blank msgbox ...

Comment: Messagebox is not a good way to debug. Try inspecting the Exception itself.

Comment: I inserted a condition to check if the InnerException is empty or not ... and apparently is always empty... keeps returns me the same message.

Comment: For the "$ is not a valid name" error, is there any chance that `hoja` is an empty string when this error occurs?

Comment: your comment guided me to light ... hahaha!

Answer (score 0):

Ok , I sat down to check everything and I had to think a little about what was happening. I discovered that my code did not have any error (that's why even though the program gave me errors , the file is modified anyway)... and discovered this too, let me explain it with an Excel file example:

[image]

Im using in my connection string the HDR property (*"HDR=Yes;" indicates that the first row contains columnnames, not data. "HDR=No;" indicates the opposite.*) as you can see , I have defined 4 columns (Name, Last name, Date, Age... not more! ).

We run the program now with this sample file and look carefully what happens:

[image]

As we saw in the first picture , I've never created a column in that position ('F1') ... apparently , there are times where you create without realizing it what I call "phantom columns " in Excel . I imagine it as the first cell of the column has nothing written on it , the program automatically gives it its name, according to their position ('F1 ' is the ghost column).

To fix this problem , when I make a query, first I check if my parameter "column " is not empty.

```
 Protected Friend Function obtenerHojaActual(ByVal columna As String, ByVal con As String) As String
    If (Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(columna)) Then
        //Blah blah
        //Blah blah
        //Blah blah
    End If
    Return "Desconocida"
End Function
```

And there we go!

[image]